# Is it possible to use jboss-log4j.xml located outside from JBOSS_HOME?

Tags: jboss, log4j, jboss5.x

Is it possible to configure JBoss 5.x to use jboss-log4j.xml located outside from JBOSS_HOME?
If yes - what should be changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `conf/jboss-service.xml` file contains the reference to `jboss-log4j.xml`:

```
<mbean code="org.jboss.logging.Log4jService"
  name="jboss.system:type=Log4jService,service=Logging"
  xmbean-dd="resource:xmdesc/Log4jService-xmbean.xml">
  <attribute name="ConfigurationURL">resource:jboss-log4j.xml</attribute>
```

I'm not sure what `resource:jboss-log4j.xml` means, exactly, but `ConfigurationURL` sounds like something you could pass in a `file://`-style URL to, specifying an external log4j file.